# Key error when I try to iterate on dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have the file text.txt with following data

```
Oscar    Morera    90
Maria    Esquivel  95 
Lucia    Benavides 80
Javier   Miranda   85
Alonso   Gonzalez  75
```

I tried to run a code to copy and sum the points of third column, but I have following error regarding the key on the dictionary:

```
data = { }
points = 0
f = open("text.txt")
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in range(len(lines)):
        # Make the line
        line = lines[i]
        # Divide it among columns.
        columns = line.split()
        # Key from student: name, last name and calification
        student = columns[0] + columns[1] + columns[2] 
        # Make float columns 2 (points)
        points = float(columns[2])
        # Iterate throw the data
        data[student] += points
for student in sorted(data.keys()):
        print(student,'\t', data[student])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test3.py", line 17, in <module>
    data[student] += points
KeyError: 'OscarMorera90'
```

I guess the error in on line : `data[student] += points`

However, I do not know how to resolve it
Please, someone can give me an advice?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? Your dictionary is initialised empty and you never add a key to it. Maybe read a tutorial about `dict` and also look into `defaultdict(int)` (from `collections` module).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. We don't exactly give advice here. Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). For us to help, you would need to clarify what you need help with. To start, do you understand what a `KeyError` is? Why do you think the error might be occurring? Also, a secondary issue, do you notice anything strange about the key `'OscarMorera90'` in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data[student] += points` is equal to `data[student] = data[student] + points`, so it will raise key error because `data` is an empty dict and it can't find the corresponding key.

You need to insert/update the `data` dict then add the value to point:

```
data = {}
points = 0
f = open('text.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    columns = line.split()
    student = f'{columns[0]} {columns[1]}'
    point = float(columns[2])
    data[student] = point
    points += point
for student in sorted(data):
    print(f'{student}\t {data[student]}')
```

Or:

```
data = {}

with open('text.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        firstname, lastname, point = line.split()
        data[f'{firstname} {lastname}'] = float(point)

    points = sum(data.values())

for student in sorted(data):
    print(f'{student}\t {data[student]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because `data` is an empty `dict`, that is you haven't given it any keys yet. Depending on what the intent of your script is, there are different ways to fix the error.

If you want a `dict` that maps names to points, you could do something like

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    # Make the line
    line = lines[i]
    # Divide it among columns.
    columns = line.split()
    # Key from student: name, last name and calification
    student = columns[0] + columns[1]
    # Iterate throw the data
    data[student] = float(columns[2])
```

If you want the total points, simply do

```
points = sum(data.values())
```

For other intents, you should edit your question and clearly state what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Beside the point, but you don't need to repeat OP's bad code in your answer. `for i in range(len(lines)): line = lines[i]` should just be `for line in lines`. Next, `# Iterate throw the data` is not what that line is doing, plus there's a typo (throw -> through). BTW, you forgot to remove "and calification" [sic].

Comment: I'm never sure if squeezing additional advice on code performance and style would help or confuse beginner OPs, so unless asked I prefer to stick to answering the question with the code they provide themselves.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = { }
points = 0
f = open("text.txt")
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in range(len(lines)):
        # Make the line
        line = lines[i]
        # Divide it among columns.
        columns = line.split()
        # Key from student: name, last name and calification
        student = columns[0] + columns[1] + columns[2] 
        # Make float columns 2 (points)
        points = float(columns[2])
        # Iterate throw the data
        if student not in data.keys():
            data[student] = points
        else:
            data[student] += points
for student in sorted(data.keys()):
        print(student,'\t', data[student])
```